# Really simple question about a specific Cauchy sequence in a generic normed space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, epsilon-delta, cauchy-sequences

**Context.** Let $X = (X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed space and $R:(X,\|\cdot\|) \longrightarrow (\Bbb K^n , \|\cdot\|_\infty)$ a linear and topological isomorphism between $X$ and $\Bbb K^n$ (here, $\Bbb K \in \{\Bbb R, \Bbb C\}).$

**Question itself.** Take any *Cauchy* sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \Bbb N} \subset X.$ Thus, by definition of *Cauchy* sequence,
$$ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N = N(\epsilon) \in \Bbb N\, : \, \forall n,m \in \Bbb N, \, n,m > N \Rightarrow \| x_n - x_m \| < \epsilon. $$
Now, one easily notes that
$$ \| R(x_n) - R(x_m)\|_\infty = \| R(x_n-x_m)\|_\infty \leqslant \| R \| \, \|x_n-x_m\| < \|R\| \, \epsilon. \quad (n,m > N) $$
Note that I used linearity of $R$, aswell as the fact that $R$ is continuous and thus bounded. And here urges my question:

I certainly can't say that $\|R\|\epsilon < \epsilon$ because this inequality is valid **only** when $\|R\| < 1.$ Normally, what people do is to define initially $\|x_n-x_m\| < \frac{\epsilon}{\|R\|}$ but again, this doesn't makes sense in my head because $\epsilon < \frac{\epsilon}{\|R\|}$ isn't valid for all values of $\|R\|$ (I am pretty sure an operator can have a norm between $0$ and $1$).

At the same time, my intuition is that the sequence $(R(x_k))_{k \in \Bbb N}$ is also *Cauchy* (in $\Bbb K^n$) but I am having some troubles with this $\epsilon$ thing... Any help would be apreciatted.

Comment: The reason we can define $\|x_n-x_m\| < \frac{\varepsilon}{\|R\|}$ initially is because what we *want to prove* is $$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N = N(\varepsilon) \in \Bbb N\, : \, \forall n,m \in \Bbb N, \, n,m > N \Rightarrow \| R(x_n) - R(x_m) \| < \varepsilon$$ however we *use* the $N\left(\frac{\varepsilon}{\|R\|}\right)$ that'd correspond to $$\forall \delta >0, \exists N = N(\delta) \in \Bbb N\, : \, \forall n,m \in \Bbb N, \, n,m > N \Rightarrow \| x_n - x_m \| < \delta$$ (I purposefully changed the name of the variable, because it's a "silent" variable)

Comment: @BrunoB So it's just like a change of variable in the original definition ?

Comment: Yes. Basically, the fact the original definition (for $(x_n)_n$) is true for all $\varepsilon$ means we're not tied to a specific one: even when we choose the $\varepsilon$ for $(R(x_n))_n$, we can still freely pick any ""$\varepsilon$"" in the original criterion, we're not tied to ours. Using different letters at first like I did in my first comment can help with the intuition to be fair.

Comment: @BrunoB Furthermore, imagine this process goes on and on: from the Cauchy sequence $R(x_k)_k$ I can say it is convergent in $\Bbb K^n$ and thus it converges to some $\alpha$. Since $R$ is surjective, for some $x \in X$, we have $R(x) = \alpha$. This leads to: $$ \|x_n - x \|  = \| R^{-1} Rx_n - R^{-1} \alpha \| \leqslant \| R^{-1}\| \, \| Rx_n - \alpha \|.   $$ Since $(Rx_k)$ converges to $\alpha$, If we take $n$ big enough, $$ \| x_n - x \| \leqslant \| R^{-1} \|\epsilon.$$ Is it okay to use the same $\epsilon$ here or does it conflict with the previous one?

Comment: I mean, as is, your statement is true, there's no conflict I don't think.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks for your help. What do you think about this "formal" formulation: Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary/given and consider $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\|R\|} > 0.$ Then, by definition of *Cauchy* sequence, we can say $$ \forall \delta >0, \exists N = N(\delta) \in \Bbb N\colon \forall n,m \in \Bbb N, n,m > N \Rightarrow \|x_n-x_m\| < \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\|R\|}.  $$ Does this look ok and clear for the reader? My only concern here is the $\forall$ quantificator for $\delta$ in the *Cauchy* sequence definition.

Comment: You should remove the $\forall \delta$ and say beforehand that you "set $\delta := ...$ in the definition of $(x_n)_n$ being Cauchy" or something like that, otherwise it'll be good yeah!

Comment: What do you think about this? Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and define $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{\|R\|} > 0.$ Thus, by definition of *Cauchy* sequence (using the $\delta$ we just defined), $$ \exists N = N(\delta) \colon \forall n,m \in \Bbb N, n,m > N \Rightarrow \|x_n-x_m\| < \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{\|R\|}. $$

Comment: It's perfect I think!

Comment: Thank you! If you want to elaborate a quick answer below so I can mark it as accepted, It would be my pleasure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(You should rename the dimension of your spaces to something that's not $n$, $m$ or something already taken, or change those to something different from the dimension, by the way.)

To sum up what's been discussed in the comments between OP and me, and so that it leaves the Unanswered category:

There seemed to be some confusion around the use of $\varepsilon$ both as the tool for the proof of $(R(x_n))_n$ being Cauchy (where it is fixed) and as the name of the variable for the definition of $(x_n)_n$ being Cauchy (where it is a "silent" variable). The critical point is that the latter can be given any value and name independent from the former's, it does not have to be *our* fixed $\varepsilon$, and this allows us to pick "$\varepsilon \leftarrow \displaystyle\frac{\varepsilon}{\|R\|}$".

A good idea at first, at least to make things clearer to the reader and/or yourself, is to begin the proof like this:
Let $(x_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. We want to prove that $(R(x_n))_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{K}^d$, that is:
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0,\,\exists N(\varepsilon) \in \Bbb N\, : \, \forall n,m \in \Bbb N, \, n,m > N(\varepsilon) \Rightarrow \| R(x_n) - R(x_m) \|_\infty < \varepsilon$$
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be fixed. Since $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy, we have:
$$\forall \delta >0,\, \exists M(\delta) \in \Bbb N\, : \, \forall n,m \in \Bbb N, \, n,m > M(\delta) \Rightarrow \| x_n - x_m \| < \delta$$
Define $N(\varepsilon) := M\left(\displaystyle\frac{\varepsilon}{\|R\|}\right)$, which is possible because $\frac{\varepsilon}{\|R\|} > 0$. [insert proof of the rest]

Hopefully that cleared any doubt around the $\varepsilon$s.